# Open file by Clicking on Hyperlink does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I want to click on the Hyperlink and the file (whatever file) should be opened in a new pop-up window.

Heres my Code:

```
 HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
 link.Text = dr.Dienstleistung.Dienstleistungsart.Dienstleister.Catering_Fax_Link;
 link.NavigateUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "\\CUSTOM\\Upload\\picture.png";
 cell.Controls.Add(link);
```

But it doesn't work with NavigateUrl. If i click on the Hyperlink nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Did you really read the [documentation for the `MapPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MapPath` gives physical path and not url. Further, use correct slashes and set target to blank so that the link would open in new window. For example,

```
link.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("~/CUSTOM/Upload/picture.png");
link.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: @VinayC I am trying your code but it's not working for [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29910618/2061309). Can you throw some light here?

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file in a popup using `window.open` and without using `NavigateUrl` property.

```
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + ResolveUrl("~/CUSTOM/Upload/picture.png") + "');");
```

Answer (score 1):

`NavigateUrl` is the URL that you will display to the user, not the filesystem path. In your case it should be:

```
link.NavigateUrl = "~/CUSTOM/Upload/picture.png";
```