# Why doesn't the hyperlink open the file?

Tags: asp.net, file, c#-4.0, hyperlink

Earlier developer had put this code using a label and it was turned into a hyperlink during the run time.

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Attachment" runat="server">
</asp:Label>

lbl_Attachment.Text = "<a href='../Uploads/" + 
                      ds_row["Attachment"].ToString() + "'>" + 
                      ds_row["Attachment"].ToString() + "</a>";
```

But this is not working. So I changed the code to the following to open the any file (image/pdf/word) in a new browser tab and the error persists:

```
      hyperlinkAppDoc.NavigateUrl = 
          ResolveUrl("../Uploads/" + 
          ds_row["Attachment"].ToString());
      hyperlinkAppDoc.Target = "_blank";
```

[image]

What can I do to fix this issue? MIME types are available in the IIS.

---

**UPDATE:**
I am trying out a different approach. However the `Server.MapPath` is poiting at local drive instead of wwwroot. How can I point the path to wwwroot folder?

```
string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~/SomeFile.pdf");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(pdfPath);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used `asp.hyperlink`. Like following

`<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="<set_from_code_behind>"                  Text="Text to redirect" runat="server"/>`

And set NavigateUrl from code behind as following.

`hyperlink1.NavigateUrl= "Uploads/" + ds_row["Attachment"].ToString();`

Comment: What is the error then? Is the datareader closed by that time? Can you try removing `..` ?

Comment: I was saying use `/` if that is in same location, you can try `~`, or let me know where is location relative to parent path.

Comment: @aspiring, updated answer, check, it should work - remove `../`

Comment: You need to make sure you are able to access the url using `http://localhost/upload/somefile.pdf` and also check the generated URL is same as above, I can see in screenshot , there is some tab/spaces in `localhost` and `/upload...`, you need check that.

Comment: Ok , then it implies, file is not present actually - I had already said in above comment - `http://localhost/upload/somefile.pdf` , check whether this works , assuming you have file in `wwwroot\TheSite\Uploads\somefile.pdf`.

Comment: Make sure you have that MIME type added to the website, if that is solved, then it implies if I have file.img, I should be able to access that file via web server.

Comment: Can you update your question with this context - like show a screenshot of IIS root dir points to abc.pdf, and when accessed abc.pdf via web server, it is not working, that will get more attention.

Comment: We can chat, this is same thing mentioned in earlier comment - check whether `http://localhost/upload/somefile.pdf`  works , assuming you have file in `wwwroot\TheSite\Uploads\somefile.pdf`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76453/discussion-between-arindam-nayak-and-aspiring).

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I suggest you to add one key in `<appSettings>` tag in your web config file.

```
<appSettings>    
    <add key="WebsiteURL" value="http://localhost:1234/WebsiteName/"/>
</appSettings>
```

Next step is to take one hyperlink in your .Aspx file.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

In code behind concatenate AppSettings Key + Download file path from root.

```
string base_path = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebsiteURL"];
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = base_path + "Uploads/" + ds_row["Attachment"].ToString();
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Nothing special, I had this 404 error 8 month ago and I solved it like this. When I went on live I had just replaced localhost url to live url and still it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All the sweat was due to path issue. Old code and new code works. There's no need for a web client code.

The upload path was set here:

`public static string UploadDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDirectory"];`

It was pointing to a different directory in the root other than where the application was. Therefore the files were only uploaded but never picked up.

I changed it to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` for now. After we talk with the users, we will set it accordingly.